# Loop em JavaScript para clicar em botão

Tags: javascript

Eu estou usando o console para clicar em um botão com o seguinte código:

```
document.getElementById('meubotao').click();
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um *loop* `for` e deixar o JavaScript clicar no botão umas 100 vezes, mas toda vez que a página recarrega dá erro.

Como eu faço para o console manter o script mesmo com a atualização da página (SPA)?

**Observação:** Eu só estou usando o console, não tenho acesso ao código fonte. Só quero facilitar meu trabalho e não ficar clicando no botão.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que para conseguir o comportamento que você precisa poderia usar a função `setInterval` ao invés de um `for`.  Tente dar 1 segundo de intervalo em cada clique para que a página possa processar (1 segundo são expressos por 1000 milisegundos na função abaixo)

```
setInterval( function(){ document.querySelector('#meubotao').click();}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas você quer dispara programaticamente 100 cliques em um botão de uma *páginas de terceiros*.

Se for eu vou dar uma resposta específica para o Chrome pois o Chrome é browser mais comum e possui na opção das Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor o console, ferramenta que permite modificar a página vigente.

Carregue a página em que quer gerar os cliques.

Pressione `[Ctrl] + [Shift] + I` para abrir as Ferramentas do Desenvolvedor.

No barra de menu selecione a opção `Elementos` e descubra o atributo `id` do botão que quer instalar o gerador de cliques.

Se o botão não possuir o atributo `id` sinto muito mas vai ter que dar 100 cliques na mão.

De posse do atributo 'id' volte a barra de menu e selecione a opção `Console`.

No console crie uma função para disparar evento programaticamente. Nesse exemplo a função chama-se `DispararEvento` que aceita um elemento da página e o nome de um evento.

```
    function DispararEvento( elemento , evento ) {
        var eventoDOM = new Event( evento ); // Cria o evento
        elemento.dispatchEvent( eventoDOM );    // Despacha o evento.
    }
```

A lógica consiste em pegar o betão pelo `id` e criar um loop que itere 100 vezes usando a função `DispararEvento` para disparar os 100 cliques.

```
   function loop(){
       for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            DispararEvento(document.getElementById(/*Aqui vai o id do botão alvo*/), "click");
       }
  }
```

Depois é só criar um botão na página que clicado invoque a função loop.

```
document.body.innerHtml += '</input><button onclick="loop();">Clicar em loop</button>';
```

Feche as ferramentas do desenvolvedor e clique no novo botão que criou e serão disparados os 100 clique contra o botão alvo.

---

Um exemplo simples dá logica envolvida, criei um `input` e dois botões um deles é o alvo(id='somar') que soma 1 ao valor do `input` e outro botão dispara 100 cliques.

```html
<script>
    // Essa função apenas soma 1 ao resultado
    function incrementar(){
      document.getElementById("resultado").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("resultado").value) + 1;
   
    }

    // Chama 100x a função DispararEvento
    function loop(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
             DispararEvento(document.getElementById("somar"), "click");
        }
    }
    
    // Dispara um evento contra um alvo
    function DispararEvento( elemento , evento ) {
        var eventoDOM = new Event( evento ); // Cria o evento
        elemento.dispatchEvent( eventoDOM );    // Despacha o evento.
    }
</script>
    <input id="resultado" type="number" value="0"></input><button id="somar" onclick="incrementar();">Somar 1</button>
    </p>
    </input><button onclick="loop();">Somar em loop</button>
```